# Override setter in Objective-c. Why check is equal parameter

Tags: objective-c, getter-setter

Often find custom setter sintaxis like this:

```
- (void)setParentCatalog:(Catalog *)parentCatalog {
    if (_parentCatalog != parentCatalog) { //???
        _parentCatalog = parentCatalog;
        [self refresh];
    }
}
```

Why i should check?

```
if (_parentCatalog != parentCatalog)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This checks if both `_parentCatalog` and `parentCatalog` are pointing to the same memory location.

If both are same object then no need to set the objectValue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for checking if the two are equal is to avoid executing code when it's not necessary. If the method is called very often, this could have a performance benefit. Under non-ARC, your code might look more like this:

```
- (void)setParentCatalog:(Catalog *)parentCatalog {
    if (_parentCatalog != parentCatalog) {
        [_parentCatalog release];
        [parentCatalog retain];

        _parentCatalog = parentCatalog;

        [self refresh];
    }
}
```

So, by checking that what you received is actually a new value, you avoid those retain and release calls happening (which are still there with ARC). You've also got `[self refresh]` in there, which probably doesn't need to happen unless the value has actually changed.

Comment: I know you are comparing the objects first, but generally you should retain first and then release. If the objects are same (not this case if you are comparing them first), you can lose it and get into memory issue. Sorry for this OT in nowadays ACR era.

Answer (score 1):

The idea here is that if the parameter passed in to the setter is the same object already stored in the property, then there is no need to call `[self refresh]` again.

A refresh method often reads in data, works on it and then re-displays it in the app's views. No need to do all this work again if the data in the property haven't really changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's a decision that is use case dependant. The idea behind this guard is to prevent doing unnecessary work.

If you imagine that your `[self refresh]` kicked off a very expensive operation then you would be reluctant to do it every time. So if you only do it when the object actually changes you save yourself some work.

Of course this may well be the behaviour you are looking for in which case you would need to stick the `[self refresh]` call outside of the guard.

Like all code examples you find it's worth weighing up the trade offs of the implementation and then you can better decide what you need in your case.